# Bind Biztalk Dynamic Port to a host instance in code/Orchestration

Tags: biztalk, orchestration, biztalk-orchestrations

I wanted to create a dynamic port which has different host instances.So I wanted to know if we can bind Biztalk Dynamic Port to a host instance in code/Orchestration.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot bind BizTalk dynamic port to a host instance. By default dynamic port takes the default host of the adapter so you can change the default host for that adapter.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible...and I really don't have an alternative.

Why do you want to do this?  Any 'performance' difference would be barely measurable.